# ASP.NET MVC Determine mime type by file/file path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, mime-types

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.
The application is targeting .net 4.0.

I was trying to pass a virtual path as argument to my controller's action and return the file without reviewing the actual physical path on the server and providing basic Authorization. Unfortunately I was unable to find a suitable overload for File method to generate the appropriate ActionResult. I am stuck at determining mime type for the file.

I've found a couple of solutions for determining mime-types by file name, but none of them are satisfying me. I was wondering how does IIS determines the mime type when you are requesting a file on the server? Is it possible to somehow pass to IIS the responsibility for determining the mime type for the response

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get MIME type from filename extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029740/get-mime-type-from-filename-extension)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are using .net 4.5 there is a function now that takes a filename and returns a mimetype:

```
MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx

Take a look at the function later in this question:

[How to use Generic Handlers (ASHX) in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636179/how-to-use-generic-handlers-ashx-in-asp-net-mvc/636720#636720)

It is a little out of date with the list of file types now but it's a start, will try to find my more recent one.

Comment: Yes thank you. I found this new cool feature. Unfortunately the application is targeting .net 4.0. Editing my question...

Comment: I do have a mime type from file ending function too if you want a copy. will have to dig out

Comment: I would really appreciate this.

Comment: Ok added reference to an answer I have given before which has an older version of the function there.